# How to use multiple images in splash screen in android

Tags: android, android-layout, splash-screen

Hello i am trying to create splash screen in android with one image but i want to display multiple images at a time in splash screen when app is launch.
but it only displays one image please any solution for this please help me.
Here is my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
                {
                    progress +=50;
                    h.post(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            pgr.setProgress(progress);
                            if(progress==pgr.getMax())
                            {
                                //pgr.setVisibility(4);
                                Intent in= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Home.class);
                                startActivity(in);
                            }

                        }
                    });
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(3000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO: handle exception
                    }

                    }
                }


        }).start();
}
}
```

Comment: Go through this link, 
http://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-build-intro-slider-app/

Comment: post your expected output

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be the use of CountDown timer,
like,

below code would change activity after 10 sec and also change image after every 1 sec (change it according to your login). int variable i to keep track of image changing number.

```
int i = 0;

new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {

public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    i++;
    if(i == 1){
        imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);
    }
    else if(i == 2){
        imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.image2);
    }
    else if(i == 3){
        imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.image3);
    }
    //and so on..........................
}

public void onFinish() {
    //finish your splash screen activity
    SplashActivity.this.finish();
}

}.start();
```